# Parsing JSON data through NATIVE Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, joomla, data-migration

I am currently on a migration process from JOOMLA database to a new native database schema using MYSQL.

I am not familiar with JOOMLA but I was able to figure out the way it saves the website content data in its database.

What I have is a set of images linked to a module, these images are saved to the database as a JSON string (am not gonna post the whole array because it's huge) :

```
"image1":"images\\/plugincabinets\\/Aeria.png",
"imageAlt1":"",
"imageHeading1":"Aeria",
"imageHeadinga1":"",
"imageHeadingb1":"",
"imageHeadingc1":"",
"imageHeadingd1":"",
"imageHeadinge1":"",
"imageText1":"",
"image1link":"#",
"image1linka":"",
"image1linkb":"",
"image1linkc":"",
"image1linkd":"",
"image1linke":"",
"image1title":"",
"enableSlide2":"true",
"image2":"images\\/plugincabinets\\/Aeria 14.png",
"imageAlt2":"",
"imageHeading2":"Aeria 14",
"imageHeadinga2":"",
"imageHeadingb2":"",
"imageHeadingc2":"",
"imageHeadingd2":"",
```

What I need is to extract the product name i.e `"imageHeading1":"Aeria" ... "imageHeading2":"Aeria 14",` and the image location `"image1":"images\\/plugincabinets\\/Aeria.png" ... "image2":"images\\/plugincabinets\\/Aeria 14.png"` from the JSON string each as a column along with the module id (which is in a different column than the column containing JSON string) and map them to my new tables.

Is there a way to get the list of images ( headings + URL) **by module id** from the table `modules` by parsing the json string without really knowing the number of images per module (each module has a random number of images in the JSON array) ?

I would prefer NATIVE mysql, I don't really prefer to use database frameworks like common_schema unless they are really fast to install and configure since am short on time for delivery.

Please advice what could be best done.

Comment: There are no native JSON functions for MySQL.

Comment: So I guess my only way is to go for a PHP solution... Right?

Comment: That, or switch to Postgres. Not only does it have native JSON functions, it is a proper RDBMS *and* has a few document/NoSQL features. edit: oh wait, Joomla. Never mind.

Comment: Mmmm interesting. Thank you!

Comment: There are JSON UDF's for MySQL: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json#readme

Comment: @AlexWoolford MYSQLUDF returns JSON data based on Table coulmns or inserts JSON data based on columns, but what I have is the other way round where I have the JSON data and I need to map some values to columns so It ain't helpful. But thank you for sharing.

Comment: MySQL is a proper RDBMS and supports JSON natively as of 5.7: http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/. Postgres implementation of JSON type is still barely functional and offers little benefits over the current MySQL functionality. I expect both to have much better support in the near future.

Comment: So the advantage of using Joomla is that it will do things like take  a json string and extract something from it.  WHy is it that you want to do this in mysql rather than with php? By the way there are lots of places in the core that do things like this. For example the images and urls fields in the #__content table or anytime parameters are extracted.   Also @Sammitch Joomla supports Postgres just fine. Is this the core modules table you are talking about?

Comment: Yes @Elin it is the core modules table. I have my own CMS that is based on Yii framework with some external plugins from cakePHP and some custom plugins I have added. I am migrating data from an exisitng JOOMLA database to a current database I have, I can do the parsing myself through PHP I don't need JOomla core functionalities but i was looking for an easy way to handle JSON with mysql natively.